# R compare all list elements for duplicates

Tags: algorithm, r, graph

I am looking at all possible paths through a graph. I have written a DFS algorithm that finds all these paths. I want to make sure that my algorithm works correctly and that no two paths are identical. My algorithm returns a list that looks as follows:

```
....
[[2770]]
 [1]   1   2   3  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  12  11  10   9   8  78  79  80 113       114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129
[38] 130 131 132 133 134 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166

[[2771]]
 [1]   1   2   3  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  12  11  10   9   8  78  79  80 113 114 115 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156
[38] 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166

[[2772]]
 [1]   1   2   3  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  12  11  10   9   8  78  79  80 113 114 115 143 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
[38] 163 164 165 166
```

As you can see, the list is 2772 elements long. This means there are 2,772 paths through this graph. How can I easily compare all the list elements to make sure there are no duplicates. Just to be clear, the same set of numbers but in a different ordering represents a different path and is not a duplicate!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe something like

```
test<-list(1:2,3:4,5:7,1:10,3:4,4:3)
dups<-duplicated(test)
idups<-seq_along(test)[dups]
```

Comment: `anyDuplicated` would be a faster check, since it only returns the location of the _first_ duplicate.